# Erro na hora de printar string

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int numero,unidade,dezena,centena;
    char *unidades[]={"I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"}; 
    char *dezenas[]={"X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC"};
    char *centenas[]={"C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM"};
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    unidade=(numero%100)%10;
    dezena=(numero%100)/10;
    centena=numero/100;
    if (centena){
        printf("%s",centena[centena-1]);
    }
    if (dezena){
        printf("%s",dezena[dezena-1]);
    }
    if (unidade){
        printf("%s",unidade[unidade-1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Então, eu estava tentando fazer o URI 1960, que consiste na conversão de um numero em base decimal para um numero em algarismos romanos, porem estou com problema na hora de imprimir a *string*.

O seguinte erro ocorre:

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>            printf("%s",centena[centena-1]);

O mesmo ocorre para as dezenas e as unidades.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que esqueceu do `s` nos nomes dos vetores:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *unidades[] = {"I", "II", "III" ,"IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"}; 
    char *dezenas[] = {"X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
    char *centenas[] = {"C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
    int numero;
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    int unidade = (numero % 100) % 10;
    int dezena = (numero % 100) / 10;
    int centena = numero / 100;
    if (centena) printf("%s", centenas[centena - 1]);
    if (dezena) printf("%s", dezenas[dezena - 1]);
    if (unidade) printf("%s", unidades[unidade - 1]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CB7w4y). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ldnlrejs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Roman.c).

Comment: Nossa q burrice minha, muito obrigado.